# Calling Lua function without executing script

Tags: c++, c, lua

I am embedding Lua into a C/C++ application.  Is there any way to call a Lua function from C/C++ without executing the entire script first?

I've tried doing this:

```
//call lua script from C/C++ program
luaL_loadfile(L,"hello.lua");

//call lua function from C/C++ program
lua_getglobal(L,"bar");
lua_call(L,0,0);
```

But it gives me this:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a nil value)
```

I can only call bar() when I do this:

```
//call lua script from C/C++ program
luaL_dofile(L,"hello.lua");  //this executes the script once, which I don't like

//call lua function from C/C++ program
lua_getglobal(L,"bar");
lua_call(L,0,0);
```

But it gives me this:

```
hello
stackoverflow!!
```

I am wanting this:

```
stackoverflow!
```

This is my lua script:

```
print("hello");

function bar()
 print("stackoverflow!");
end
```

Comment: Since you have to run the script to get the Lua VM to see it like Etan indicated you'll have to extract out `function bar()` to a different file and just run that file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As was just discussed in #lua on freenode luaL_loadfile simply compiles the file into a callable chunk, at that point none of the code inside the file has run (which includes the function definitions), as such in order to get the definition of bar to execute the chunk must be called (which is what luaL_dofile does).

Comment: I was the person who asked that on the chat :P

Comment: I figured you were, but figured I'd make the reference explicit anyway, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the script must be run to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution / hack (and *please* bear in mind that I'm currently unable to test this)...

---

Insert a dummy "return;" line at the top of your LUA code.

- Load your file into a string (like you would in preparation for using `luaL_loadstring()`)
- Now it should be a simple matter of using `printf_s("return;\r\n%s", [pointer to string holding actual LUA code])`
- Now you can `luaL_loadstring()` the concatenated string

The code will still execute, but it should get cut off before it can actually reach anything that does something (in your `print("hello");` example, the print line would become unreachable). It **should** still have updated the list of all the function prototypes and you should now be able to use `lua_get()` to reference the functions.

---

NOTE: For those who don't know **"\r\n"** are the escape codes representing a newline on the Windows OS, and it **MUST** be those slashes...   IE: THIS **\r\n**       ***NOT*** THIS **/r/n**